# Change the font size and font style of UISearchBar UISegmentedControl in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I change the font of the UIButtons in the scope bar of a UISearchBar?
The font of the UISearchBar input I have already changed but this does not change it for the scope bar.

[image]

With this code I changed the UISearchBar text font and color in my AppDelegate.m.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:FONT_COLOR, NSFontAttributeName:NAVIGATION_BAR_FONT}];
```

Comment: paste ur code instead of screenshot

Comment: how or where should I embed your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**u can use this code:**

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ur font name" size:10];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName]; 
[your segmentName setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Your saved my day! Thanks